# Spring 3.0 Expression Langugage Java Generic Parameters

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-el

I'm using Spring 3 and I have a class with a static method with the signature `My.Package.MyClass.build(Map<MyObject1,MyObject2> map)`. In my spring bean file, I have the following:

```
<constructor-arg index="1"
        value="#{T(My.Package.MyClass).build(TheMap)}" />

<util:map id="TheMap">
 ...add map entries...
</util:map>
```

When I run this I get an error saying that the method `build(java.util.LinkedHashMap)` cannot be found on `My.Package.MyClass` type. I did some testing and when I remove the generics from the method signature it works fine. I would think this conversion would work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
            ">

    <bean id="object1" class="sk.matejtymes.elTest.Object1"/>
    <bean id="object2" class="sk.matejtymes.elTest.Object2"/>

    <util:map id="theMap">
        <entry key-ref="object1" value-ref="object2"/>
    </util:map>

    <bean id="elTestClass" class="sk.matejtymes.elTest.ElTestClass">
        <constructor-arg index="0"
            value="#{T(sk.matejtymes.elTest.ElTestClass).build(theMap)}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and class this test class:

```
public class ElTestClass {

    private Map<Object1, Object2> map;


    public ElTestClass(ElTestClass orig) {
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<Object1, Object2>(orig.map);
    }


    private ElTestClass(Map<Object1, Object2> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }


    public static ElTestClass build(Map<Object1, Object2> map) {
        return new ElTestClass(map);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/elTest/application-context.xml");

        ElTestClass elTestClass = context.getBean(ElTestClass.class);

        System.out.println(elTestClass);
    }
}
```

note: classes Object1 and Object2 are totally empty.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'll go back to my code and try to figure out what is different.

Comment: maybe if you would post some snippet of your code, the problem might be more visible